# Making offset effect for div container

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Im trying to make something like this:

[Div Container with offset effect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hzSme.png)

im trying to make a container that also has an offset effect like in the image,
any ideas?

Comment: take a look at box-shadow property .

Comment: thanks alot man!!, i didnt know that box-shadow could be solid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[box-shadow Docs](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_box-shadow.asp)

Use the property `box-shadow`. The third parameter is `blur`, you can set it to 0 or leave blank and the shadow will be solid.

So in your CSS you can do this: `box-shadow: 10px 10px 0;`